# Create stored function to retrieve total amount between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a stored function and just want to retrieve total amount by following query but ouput is null please let me know whats wrong in it

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION demo6(a DATE , b DATE) 
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `total` FROM
`temp_sale` WHERE `transaction_date` 
BETWEEN a AND b); 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "ouput is null" can just mean that no rows have been found for your BETWEEN condition. Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Suleman . .  Please show how the function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is returning `NULL`, then the query is returning `NULL`.  This query:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `total`
FROM `temp_sale`
WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN a AND b;
```

returns `NULL` whenever there are no rows that match the `WHERE` clause.  So, your result is probably due to either an empty table or having no rows match the conditions.

A secondary reason could be the presence of columns called `a` or `b` in `temp_sale`.  I strongly recommend giving function and stored procedure parameters prefixes to help avoid naming conflicts:

```
CREATE FUNCTION demo6 (
    in_date_first DATE,
    in_date_last DATE
) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(ts.amount)
            FROM temp_sale ts
            WHERE ts.transaction_date BETWEEN in_date_first AND in_date_last); 
END$$
```